# Reset configuration in windows 8 account

Tags: windows-8

I using Windows 8, and I have a problem on system and I needed to reinstall all system. But, the configuration is saved in the account, and when he was done he pulled synchronization, for example, until the folder options I had.

How do I reset these settings saved in my account? I want to sync, but I want sync all clean these saved settings.

Help me all, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the system without losing settings or documents. You will need to reinstall your applications though.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

Comment: Sorry my friend, but I need losing settings or documents linked the account. I just do not want to keep.

Comment: @user2465422: If you want a fresh start then just Reset instead of Refresh, simple.